Define X_AFTER_HOMING for X axis?
I am just trying to get to understand how to solve an X-axis off-plate problem. I am on Marlin 2.1.2.4 paired with Repetier.
What is currently happening to me is that when homing the axes, the nozzle is 1.6 cm off the plate on the X-axis.
When setting the home I have got to understand that basically either Repetier or Marlin intends the home position ( = 0) when and where the endstop is activated.
What would be ideal for me is to have a setting like define Z_AFTER_HOMING but for the X-axis. But I could not find anything like that.
I tried to edit X_MIN and X_MAX positions to obtain a result... but what apparently seems logical to me was not to the firmware and Repetier. Basically, by changing those settings I was telling Repetier that when the endstop is activated rather than read the coordinate there as 0, if X_MAX is 160 mm, it would read it as 160. When, instead, I need the X to physically move forward of 160 mm.

I think you need to read: "How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)", this should give you the information you need to set the offset. You  need to define the offsets from the endstops.

Thanks for the reading Oscar, I managed to calibrate the homing offset.

No problem, you are welcome, we will mark this as a duplicate if that question helped you. If you have a different solution, you could post it here.
